# Convert a byte for char A

Tags: javascript, parsing, binary, hex, converters

In javascript I would like to convert this string: `'0x7f, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0x88, 0x7f'`
to an object that look like this:

```
['B00000000','B01111111','B10001000','B10001000','B10001000','B10001000','B01111111','B00000000']
```

Both are displaying char A on a 8*8 Led matrix. How to do this in Javascript?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I would like to know how to convert this in Javascript and I dont understand what 0x7f, 0x88... mean.

Comment: Split the string into separate hex values, then convert each one and store in an array. I'm sure you can google to find out how to convert from hex to binary.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know it was called HEX.

Comment: `0x` is commonly used to indicate a hex value

Comment: fyi, your input would need to to begin and end with `0x00` to produce the output you show

Comment: If you didn't know this was Hex (hexadecimal) then you might be as well to give [something like this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal.html) a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't write your code as you should really figure it out for yourself, but I will give you the (possible) process...

- Split the string using `.split` function into an array
- Loop through the
  array and convert the Hex to int and store in a new array
- Loop
  through the new array and convert the ints to the B1111111 format
  required. You can do this by starting with 128 and shifting right (or
  halving) on each iteration. Compare to the int, if larger you get a 1
  and subtract from the int. If not larger you get a 0. Add these 1s
  and 0s onto a string and you have the binary representation. Add these strings into a new array, which will be your final result.

You can create an array with `var arrayName = [];` and then add to it with `arrayName.push(someString);`

Good luck!